# Flutter: ListTile with a TextFormField title and a subtitle

Tags: flutter

When I try to create a ListTile with a title containing a TextFormField, I can't add a subtitle or it blows up.

Here's a simple example:

```
ListTile(
  title: TextFormField(
    initialValue: 'foo',
  ),
  subtitle: const Text('bar'),
),
```

When I add this snippet to my code and run it, I get:

```
I/flutter (20366):   RenderParagraph#3f385 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (20366): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (20366): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#76527 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (20366): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#61d3e relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (20366): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#eaf9a relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (20366): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#479d1 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (20366): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#1419c relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (20366): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 310 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter (20366): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
D/        (20366): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd0a0ab40, tid 20389
W/        (20366): Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions:
```

Is this a bug or is this just an invalid request?

My end goal is to create a TextFormField that shows a label and the units.  For example, a field where the user can type a value for a measured distance in feet.

Comment: it looks like is an error related to your parent constraints, what is the parent of that widget?

Comment: Open Issue - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18755

Comment: @diegoveloper The parent of the ListTile is a Column which is the body of a Scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

The error "RenderBox was not laid out" occurs when the widget is unable to fetch the parent widget's dimension. I tried running the snippet with a similar setup to what you have mentioned and it works without issues on Flutter 3.10.5.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          title: TextFormField(
            initialValue: 'foo',
          ),
          subtitle: const Text('bar'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: TextFormField(
            initialValue: 'foo',
          ),
          subtitle: const Text('bar'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: Demo]

See if there are other widgets in the Screen that could cause for the `ListTile` to be unable to identify the constraints of `Column`.